# How can I slide a new string from an array into a sentence every n seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I slide text out and in to replace one word in a sentence?

Here's the sentence:

```
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum</span> dolor sit.</p>
```

I need to slide the word inside the `<span>` up and slide a new word in from the bottom.

The goal is to have an array of words that rotate in every *n* seconds.  For example, given the following array:

```
var myArr = new Array('ipsum','alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon');
```

How can I replace (via `.slideUp()`, I expect) the existing word with the next in the array?

I'm expecting the end result to somewhat resemble how an odometer might acts, but with text.  Make sense?

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: http://nleach.com/post/16045448547/odometer-style-counter-using-jquery  or http://www.frontendmatters.com/demos/jodometer/

Comment: Cycle looks great, but I'd rather not add a complex plugin for a simple problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might try

```
var myArr = new Array('ipsum','alpha','beta','gamma','delta','epsilon');

myArr.push(myArr.shift());
```

- myArr.shift() gives you "ipsum"
- myArr.push() puts it in the end.

**Edit** :

Ok Ryan, here is a solution, you could use a better animation, but this is for the sake of the example.
And I was wrong first with the pop(), since that's shift() you need here ! (edited as well)

> use this in the html :

```
        <span id="mySpan">plop</span>
```

> use this for javascript with jquery :

```
var myArr = new Array('ipsum ','alpha ','beta ','gamma ','delta ','epsilon ');
    loop();

    function loop() 
    {
        $("#mySpan").slideUp(3000, function(){
            myArr.push(myArr.shift());

            $("#mySpan").empty();
            $("#mySpan").append(myArr[0]);
            $("#mySpan").show(200);

            loop();
        });
    }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eL3eG/

Comment: The OP is looking for the animation of the words as well.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't go far enough, but even the pop, push is helpful.  I need to do a `foreach` and `.slideup()` through it.  ;)  Any tips?  Upvoted.  Any further help, Chris?

Comment: I edited the answer, I hope you find enough hint to do want you want.
Thanks for the upvote : )

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I'm curious what clears the animation down?  The animation pushes word down to hide, then springs up.  But the js doesn't say slideDown ever.

Comment: You're welcome. I guess .show() is what does the trick. It does the same animation in these examples http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 2):

Without writing the code for you, i've put together a brief text switching example for you. I've used `.slideUp()` to provide animation though you may want to use `.animate()` if you want finer control and make it more odometre'ish. I hope this gives you some idea on how you can achieve this.

[jSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9fRcX/5/)

Rough HTML

```
<div class="widget-container">
    <p>Lorem</p>
    <div class="widget-vert-rotate">
        <!-- jQuery elements will be here -->
    </div>
    <p>dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

Put them all in line. Vertical align top is to make sure that the animation will always put the next word inline with the sentance. Some right padding as well to emulate word spacing. Finally set a height for the rotator container and set its overflow to hidden.

```
.widget-container > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 0.4em;
}

.widget-vert-rotate {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.1em;
}
```

And the JS + jQuery

```
var words = ['ipsum','nunc','telum'],
    i = 0,
    l = words.length,
    el = $('.widget-vert-rotate'),
    t = 3000;

// Create the text elements
for ( ; i < l ; i++ ) {
    $('<p />').text(words[i]).appendTo(el);
}

// Set the interval function
var itv = setInterval(function() {
    var child = el.children().first();
    child.slideUp(1000, function() {
        child.remove();

        el.append(
            $('<p />').text(child.text())
        );
    });
}, t);
```

Comment: lol.  So much for not writing the code for me.  This is great.  Thanks.